# loss.back() error on MPS mac for LSTM (works on CPU)

Tags: pytorch, apple-m1

Python version: 3.10.6
pytorch version: 1.12.1 (nightly build)

I'm trying to run a LSTM network on a macbook pro M1. The code runs perfectly on CPU but when I change my device to GPU (mps), loss.backward() throws the following error:

> RuntimeError: Expected a proper Tensor but got None (or an undefined Tensor in C++) for argument #0 'grad_y'

Tbh I don't know how to debug this and what the problem might be. Probably a grad issue since error is for argument grad_y. But why does it work on the CPU?

My code:

```
class ShallowRegressionLSTM(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, num_sensors, hidden_units, num_layers=1, out_features=1):
        super(ShallowRegressionLSTM, self).__init__()
        self.num_sensors = num_sensors  # this is the number of features
        self.hidden_units = hidden_units
        self.num_layers = num_layers
        self.out_features = out_features

        self.lstm = nn.LSTM(
            input_size=num_sensors,
            hidden_size=hidden_units,
            batch_first=True,
            num_layers=self.num_layers
        )

        self.linear = nn.Linear(in_features=self.hidden_units, out_features=self.out_features)

    def forward(self, x):
        batch_size = x.shape[0]
        h0 = torch.zeros(self.num_layers, batch_size, self.hidden_units, requires_grad=True, device=device)
        c0 = torch.zeros(self.num_layers, batch_size, self.hidden_units, requires_grad=True, device=device)
        
        _, (hn, _) = self.lstm(x, (h0, c0)) #Outputs: output, (h_n, c_n)
        out = self.linear(hn[-1]).flatten()  # First dim of Hn is number layers
        return out
```

```
def train_model(data_loader, model, loss_function, optimizer):
    num_batches = len(data_loader)
    total_loss = 0
    model.train()

    for X, y in data_loader:
        X = X.to(device)
        y = y.to(device)    
        output = model(X)
        
        loss = loss_function(output, y)
        optimizer.zero_grad()
        loss.backward()
        optimizer.step()

        total_loss += loss.item()

    avg_loss = total_loss / num_batches
    print(f"Train loss: {avg_loss}")
    train_loss.append(avg_loss)
```

tried loss on gpu too.

```
model = ShallowRegressionLSTM(num_sensors=len(features), hidden_units=num_hidden_units, num_layers=num_layers).to(device)
#loss_function = nn.MSELoss().to(device)
loss_function = nn.MSELoss()
optimizer = torch.optim.Adam(model.parameters(), lr=learning_rate)
```

```
for epoch in range(epochs):
    train_model(train_loader, model, loss_function, optimizer=optimizer)
```

Only post around this issue i've found:
https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/loss-backward-error-when-using-m1-gpu-mps-device/152306

I've tried the following:

- loss on gpu and cpu
- retain_grad
- tried to push output and label to cpu before loss

to fix: #0 'grad_y'.

Comment: when using gru instead of LSTM it does work on gpu